# Throw an exception when line is above 80 (java)

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to write a program which takes a java file as input (which is specified in the program) and reads through it line by line. If a line is longer than 80 characters it throws an exception, if the exception is thrown the program prints the line that is too long and continues the process with the rest of the program.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LinePolice
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws LinePoliceTooLongException
   {
      try
      {
         File file = new File("NameOrientation.java");
         FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
         StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
         String line;
         while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
         {
            LinePoliceTooLongException x = new LinePoliceTooLongException(line); 
            if (line.length() > 80)
               throw x;
         }
         fileReader.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {

      }
   }
}


public class LinePoliceTooLongException extends Exception
{
   LinePoliceTooLongException(String message)
   {
      super(message);
   }
}
```

When I run it with the following file it picks up the first line longer than 80 but does not continue through the file.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NameOrientation
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("NameOrientation");

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel primary = new JPanel();
      primary.setBackground(Color.green);
      primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));

      JLabel label1 = new JLabel("********************************************************");
      JLabel label2 = new JLabel("**************************************************************");

      primary.add(label1);
      primary.add(label2);

      frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

If possible can someone tell me where I am going wrong and what I can do to try and get this to work. Thanks for any and all help

Comment: How are you going to continue the loop if you throw exception?

Comment: The exception is thrown, so your main method halts and the program exits.

Why do that when you can use an if/else statement instead?

Comment: It's also a bad idea to "proactively" create `Exception` objects like you do here, because stack traces are very expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                LinePoliceTooLongException x = new LinePoliceTooLongException(line); 
                try{
                    if (line.length() > 80)
                       throw x;
                }catch(LinePoliceTooLongException le){
                    System.out.println("Line:"+line);
                }
             }
```

Since you are throwing LinePoliceTooLongException from while loop and not catching it, you are unable to continue for rest of the lines. You have to catch the exception in while loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating the exception

```
 LinePoliceTooLongException x = new LinePoliceTooLongException(line);
```

throwing it and you are not catching it. Thats is why your program is not completing properly. I think that you would have understood that by now.

To solve this, you can add `catch` block to catch the exception that you have just thrown. If you do this, that will be really a horrible, there is no meaning in throwing an exception and catching it right after it's thrown. Whatever you want to do in `catch block` do it inside your `if` and don't throw any exception.

```
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
     {
       if (line.length() > 80){
          System.out.println("Line is more than 80 characters and can not be processed: " + line);
     }
 }
```